# c# serial port multiple requests and responses

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

Sorry if this question looks awkward.

i am developing a GUI(win forms) in c#. The purpose of the GUI is to send data packets to a controller and get the data back. these events are performed by buttons.

Sending single request and receiving data back is fine. But I have multiple text boxes to send data to controller and every text box mean a new packet going out from GUI to controller.

So my question is how can I implement a kind of acknowledgment for example If I send one request to controller and wait for its response for 10ms if I get the response back from the controller then send the new packet otherwise just discard the new packet.

I have an event to receive the data from the ports and displaying it in text-boxes after decoding but for the responses i will have a rich-text-box terminal.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is based on what I got from your question

If you want to perform this serialization at your GUI side, u can lock the instance of your GUI.

for waiting sharp 10ms, your request should be asynchronies request because Sync Request will add it's own processing time here. 
it will be  something like this

```
lock(curGUI)
{
    MakeAsyncReq(Param reqParam);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: hi Amit actually i have got the answer. i have added flags for that also with your concept.

Thanks